# Using command line arguments in MAUI and .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, maui

I am making one of my first .Net MAUI apps and me and my team are working with different databases: a dev, a test and a master database. In some of our older projects we used the debug arguments to set the database we were working in. For this new project we are also using .Net Core for the first time and I see that in the project properties, instead of a field to place the command line arguments, you must now make a launch profile. Which works for other projects like WPF projects since the working directory is the `bin/debug` folder. But in MAUI, it is not clear which folder I need to use.

If I make it platform specific, So I make a Windows + Dev launch profile I would give in the command line argument `DEV|` and the working directory `ProjectFolder\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64`. Which is where you find the `.exe`.

If I use this I get this error (Error for Windows + dev launch):

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this firstly for windows and also for android. Or is there an alternative, where I can setup which database to use without changing the code?

Comment: How about a secure configuration setting that is then used with dependency injection to select the runtime database for whatever build you're running. Admittedly you would need to change the value when running a test or debug build.